# Is each instance of Tk() class running independent of each other?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have been learning how to make GUIs with Tkinter and a question has occurred to me. As I'm testing the program, I often end up building the code while an instance of it already exists in the background. Are these two independent of each other in terms of performing their functions? I've always read that when I create the instance of the Tk() and then run its mainloop(), that is what takes care of everything. Can I have two or more loops running if each pertains to a different Tk() instance?

Comment: What do you mean by: **1.** *I often end up building the code while an instance of it already exists in the background.* ? **2.** *Can I have two or more loops running?* Do you meanin `mainloop()`?

Comment: While I'm testing the code, I will run the code to test the functionality of my program. Sometimes I don't close this before running the code again and so I have two instances running at the same time. I wanted to know whether these are two separate instances and if my thinking was correct.

Comment: Yes, I mean mainloop(). Thanks.

Comment: **1.**  Each `Tkinter.Tk()` instance is an independant process. **2.** No, you can not have more than one `mainloop()`

Comment: I meant a total number of `mainloop()` arising from multiple `Tkinter.Tk()` instances.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem in that case because they are independent processes

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `Tk` is separate from any other instance of `Tk`. It gets its own copy of an underlying tcl interpreter. Two instance of `Tk` in the same process means you have two active tcl interpreters.

As a general rule you should only ever have exactly one instance of `Tk`, but I suppose if you fully understand how they work, it should be possible to have two or more.

I think this falls into the category of things you shouldn't do until you understand why you shouldn't do them. And once you understand, you won't want to do it.

Comment: Why could it be bad to have two instances of `Tk` running?

Comment: @SebastianFreeman: It won't be bad per se, it just likely won't behave the way you expect. For one, it will require multiple threads which always leads to complicated code. If you need multiple widows there are much better solutions than to try and have two instances of `Tk`.

Comment: @SebastianFreeman: as soon as you need to run a second call to `mainloop`.