# Tkinter: why do both windows open?

Tags: python, loops, methods, tkinter

I started looking at some Tkinter tutorials. I always like to mess around with code before going on with the next chapter: for instance I tried to open more than one independent root.

```
from Tkinter import *

def main():
    root1, root2 = Tk(), Tk()
    root1.title("First window")
    root2.title("Second window")
    root1.mainloop()
    root2.mainloop()

main()
```

What I don't understand is why this code works (i.e. it shows two different windows at the same time).
If the Tk "mainloop" method is a loop, why do I see the second window? Shouldn't I see it only after closing the first window (i.e. after breaking the first while loop)?

Please, explain me how it works

Comment: It is irrelevant how it works (or doesn't work). This isn't correct usage of Tkinter. You should only ever create exactly once instance of `Tk` at a time.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is indeed just a basic fundamental concept.

Comment: Either it is irrelevant or it is a basic fundamental concept ... :/ I don't get it.
I'm checking out 4-5 tutorials and neither makes any reference to this

Comment: You have created two instances of `Tk` at the same time; then given a `mainloop()` for each of them. A `Tk` window pops-up right after you create it. Again, you have defined two of them at the same time which means they both will pop-up at the same time when the program starts. It is simple as that. What else were you expecting? That is why I am telling it is a fundamental concept of `Tkinter`. If you have not understood it, I would recommend you to start from the the beginning -- the basics -- again (if you actually had done it before).

Comment: "why do I see the second window? Shouldn't I see it only after closing the first window?" -Nope. In order to get that check this code out: http://pastebin.com/iLPsU7Mc

Comment: In the pastebin link I provided above as you can see, first, I have created the first instance of `Tk`, then given it a title, then put it in a `mainloop`, and only after that I have created the second instance of `Tk`, and then the same process with this one too. But the problem is not this. The problem is as @BryanOakley has already stated [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417091/tkinter-why-do-both-windows-open#comment66159271_39417091): "This isn't correct usage of Tkinter. You should only ever create exactly once instance of `Tk` at a time."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is each instance of Tk() class running independent of each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141010/is-each-instance-of-tk-class-running-independent-of-each-other)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Removed incorrect answer, added answer below**

The short of why are confused is that the behavior of your code is undefined. Really, it isn't running as differently as you think. Try running this code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def main():
    root1, root2 = Tk(), Tk()
    root1.title("First window")
    root2.title("Second window")

    root1.mainloop()
    print 'root1.mainloop() has finished running.'
    root2.mainloop()
    print 'root2.mainloop() has finished running.'

main()
```

So the first `mainloop` doesn't actually continue on immediately. It hangs on `root1.mainloop()` (as you expected) until you close both of the windows, then it continues on. I am not sure exactly why running `root1.mainloop()` opens both windows as I don't have access to all of the source code but I think it would be a little bit like asking about the results of `0/0`. It just isn't supposed to happen.

Comment: no, tkinter runs in a single thread -- whichver thread it is created in. A good, concise description is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38767665/7432

Comment: Sorry about that (to anyone that read my original answer). I am editing it now.