# How to create window independent each other?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create independent window. each create window, when caller window close or destroy.
so far is create window without problem. but console warning message that i dont know what is this.

Console warning

> can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed
> while executing "event generate $w <>"
> (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
> invoked from within "ttk::ThemeChanged"

```
import tkinter

class MainWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, condition):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Main Window ")
        self.geometry("640x360")

        if (condition == 1):
            DashboardWindow() 
            self.destroy()
            

class DashboardWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Dashboard Window")
        self.geometry("940x560")

    
    
MainWindow(1).mainloop()
```

Comment: `tk.Tk()` is considered as the root of your application and to code with 2 root windows is a complete mess. Rather you could write 2 programs and run a program where those are running simultaneously.

Comment: See [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: @Atlas435 No it's not a complete mess. Right now OP is calling `self.destroy()` and then trying to call `.mainloop()`. That will obviously crash the program as the `tk.Tk` window no longer exists.

Comment: @TheLizzard I thought the destroy method is just called to demonstrate what OP is trying to achive. Otherwise the title of this question is missleading. *How to create window independent each other?*

Comment: @Atlas435 OP is trying to create windows independent of each other but accidentally calls `.mainloop()` after `.destroy()`. And to create windows that are independent of each other, you need to use multiple instances of `tk.Tk()`.

Comment: @TheLizzard I can see how you interpret the question. No need to explain.

Comment: The `ttk::ThemeChanged` error is a Tk bug: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/310c74ecf440

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to avoid having more than on instance of `Tk` in your application for the reasons stated in the link in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69060645/how-to-create-window-independent-each-other#comment122057496_69060645) I posted under your question.

So below is code showing one way to do that based on what's in your question. In it the `DashboardWindow` class is derived from tkinter's [`Toplevel`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html) widget. Note that the `MainWindow` instance is only *hidden* so isn't destroyed, which means it could be made visible again (via a `root.state('normal')` call if desired). To demonstrate that I added a `Button` to the `DashboardWindow` class.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, condition):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Main Window ")
        self.geometry("640x360")

        if condition == 1:
            new = DashboardWindow(self)
            self.wait_visibility(new)  # Wait until it's visible.
            self.withdraw()  # Hide MainWindow


class DashboardWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title("Dashboard Window")
        self.geometry("940x560")

        tk.Button(self, text='Main window', command=lambda: parent.state('normal')).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = MainWindow(1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Even though the `MainWindow` is hidden it still requires computational power and still lives in memory. Also those 2 windows aren't independent and I disagree with the answer in link you posted.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I know the hidden window requires some negligible resources — but hardly more than its base class...and that you disagree with linked answer since you've mentioned it before on other questions. Guess we can agree to disagree since I feel Bryan Oakley has more credibility wrt to `tkinter` than you (and I personally have never needed more than one instance).

Comment: I know that BryanOakley has more credibility than me but I still stand behind my point. If someone can give me am example where creating 2 `tk.Tk` windows causes problems other than the one I said in my question, I will reconsider my point.

Comment: @TheLizzard: Well, Brian explained to you in more detail [once](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley), plus I think it just makes things more error-prone. However I do agree with you about the OP's design possibly being flawed. It sounds to me like there's a main window and some subsidiary ones, so it doesn't make sense to destroy the primary one because it'll be needed again — which my answer allows and is another reason I think it's the better one thus far (beyond merely the fact that it's following Oakley's advice).

Answer (score 1):

Right now you create a `tk.Tk` window, then call `.destory()` on it and then call `.mainloop()` on it. The `.destroy()` will destroy the window so you can no longer call any normal `tkinter` methods on it like `.mainloop()`

This is your code fixed:

```py
import tkinter


class MainWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, condition):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Main Window ")
        self.geometry("640x360")

        if (condition == 1):
            new_window = DashboardWindow()
            self.destroy()
            # We will call .mainloop() here:
            new_window.mainloop()


class DashboardWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("Dashboard Window")
        self.geometry("940x560")


# After this is done, the window will no longer be allive so we can't call `.mainloop()`
MainWindow(1)
```

I think that your design is flawed. You can have multiple `tk.Tk` windows (so the windows are independent of each other) but you have to pass in `master=...` when creating `PhotoImage`s/`StringVar`s/`IntVar`s/... And it doesn't matter how many `tk.Tk` windows you have, don't call any methods on widgets/windows that have been destroyed.

Comment: [You should know better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67007762/13629335)

Comment: @Atlas435 The `.mainloop()` handles events from all `tk.Tk` windows. So as long as you have 1 `.mainloop()` there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: `mainloop()` is called by default. If you run a script without calling mainloop it calls it automatically.

Comment: @Atlas435 No. `.mainloop()` is called by the python interpreter if it's in interactive mode. Try: `import tkinter as tk; root = tk.Tk()` and from CMD use `python filename.py`. The program will end immediately without showing the window.

Comment: @TheLizzard i get same console error when i close application. to make simple i dont use class  in here `root = tkinter.Tk()
roo1 = tkinter.Tk()
root.destroy()
roo1.mainloop()`

Comment: @TheLizzard console not error if close manually by click button. but using method destroy give console error.

Comment: @davidstephen First you destroy the window then you try calling `.mainloop()` on it. You can't call any `tkinter` methods without the widget still being alive (there are some rare exceptions). That is the problem.

Comment: @davidstephen if you manually close the window, that happens after the `.mainloop()` has started.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? I solved the question and my answer works so why the downvote?

Comment: @TheLizzard if so, i try put root.destroy() in latest line. it get same error. `root = tkinter.Tk()
roo1 = tkinter.Tk()
roo1.mainloop()
root.destroy()`

Comment: @davidstephen In that case you call `root1.mainloop()` which only stops when the user closes the window and the you call `.destroy()`. So you are calling `.destroy()` on a window that has been destroyed by the user. That is still the same problem as before.

Comment: @TheLizzard  mainloop can share to many object tk, right? i try call mainloop first before i call to destroy specific window.

Comment: @TheLizzard I dont want to argue with you once again about this. As I said last time, `tkinter` wasnt designed this way and you cant think this through. Its a bad advice.

Comment: @TheLizzard ow, mainloop only listen to widget event ( button, check, radio ), right? mainloop cant listen to programmatically call.

Comment: @Atlas435 Care to give me an example where my advice doesn't work? Also this question isn't caused by the multiple instances of `tk.Tk`. The only problem I have seen so far caused by the multiple `tk.Tk` windows is the one where people don't pass in `master=...` when creating their tkinter variables/images.

Comment: @davidstephen The `.mainloop()` handles all events from all `tk.Tk` windows but you can only call `.mainloop()` on a window that is still alive.

Comment: @TheLizzard if like that, is not put root.destroy() in latest line. it should not be problem.

root window still exist. second window call main loop method, and it still exist. after root.destroy() call

Comment: @davidstephen As I said, you can only call `.mainloop()` on a window that is still alive. If you keep a reference to the `DashboardWindow` and cal `.mainloop()` on that, it should work.

Comment: @TheLizzard I dont think this practice is necesarry. Therefore I wont work this idea out with you.

Comment: @Atlas435 There are cases where you might want windows that are independent of each other. But if you don't want to argue, I am fine.

Comment: @TheLizzard as I stated in the first place. For this case you can run 2 scripts simultaneously, without mind all the sideeffects of this practice.

Comment: @Atlas435 I assume you mean in multiple processes, then communication between the 2 windows will be difficult. But it is possible to do that.

Comment: @TheLizzard the method I would prefere depends on what I want to achive. There is no general solution for complexity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236779/discussion-between-atlas435-and-thelizzard).